# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN with VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

Before installing VirtualBox or VMware Workstation, my VPN Connection (L2TP/IPSEC PSK) works without any problems. I'm able to reach every Site I want.

But after one of them are installed I getting this error message at **several** sites with Chrome (Edge and Firefox won't load too, but without giving me an detailed error message), e.g. the whole StackExchange Network.

My Android Phone didn't have this issue (connected to the same VPN, of course)

I tried all the nice things that i found with google.

flushing/renew/release dns (and other crazy command line commands)  -> **no success**
Set DNS-Server manually -> **no success**
Even after uninstalling -> **no success**
2 weeks without Vmware/VirtualBox (after complete Windows-Reset) -> **SUCCESS**

My question now: Is it possible to get back the functionality without to give up on VirtualBox or Vmware? Any Ideas, some magic spells?

Server = QNAP-NAS
Client = Windows 10

Many thanks.

**UPDATE #1**
Twisty Impersonator ask me to run nslookup on an inaccessible-site. Superuser.com is on of them:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup -d2 superuser.com
------------
SendRequest(), len 42
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (91 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  168.192.in-addr.arpa
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 37
        ttl = 1278 (21 mins 18 secs)
        primary name server = localhost
        responsible mail addr = root
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 604800 (7 days)
        retry   = 86400 (1 day)
        expire  = 2419200 (28 days)
        default TTL = 604800 (7 days)

------------
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

------------
SendRequest(), len 31
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
Fehler bei SendRequest.
------------
SendRequest(), len 31
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (121 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  superuser.com
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 78
        ttl = 265 (4 mins 25 secs)
        primary name server = ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
        responsible mail addr = cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 21600 (6 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 259200 (3 days)
        default TTL = 300 (5 mins)

------------
------------
SendRequest(), len 31
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
Fehler bei SendRequest.
------------
SendRequest(), len 31
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (121 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        superuser.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  superuser.com
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 78
        ttl = 263 (4 mins 23 secs)
        primary name server = ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
        responsible mail addr = cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 21600 (6 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 259200 (3 days)
        default TTL = 300 (5 mins)

------------
*** Zeitüberschreitung bei Anforderung an UnKnown.
```

**Update 2**
Output of ipconfig /all (Client)

```
Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC-Name
   Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . :
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-V
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 1C-39-47-98-0E-7D
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Ethernet-Adapter DockingStation:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-4C-12-34-72
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 10-02-B5-A1-01-30
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter LAN-Verbindung* 1:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 10-02-B5-A1-01-31
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Ethernet-Adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::7451:972d:1387:c71b%3(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.150.1(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100683862
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-D1-6A-BB-1C-39-47-98-0E-7D
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert

Ethernet-Adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::e41e:4322:d30b:524c%7(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.1(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 6. Januar 2018 08:17:58
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 6. Januar 2018 17:02:57
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.254
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 738218070
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-D1-6A-BB-1C-39-47-98-0E-7D
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert

PPP-Adapter MyVPN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : MyVPN
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.0.2(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert

Mobiler Breitbandadapter Mobilfunk:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : HUAWEI Mobile Broadband Module
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 8C-9A-88-55-59-53
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::b91d:5c86:6ce7:c88e%15(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.78.75.185(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.78.75.186
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 62.109.121.17
                                       62.109.121.18
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Tunneladapter LAN-Verbindung* 12:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:78cf:28bb:225b:f5fd:fffd(Bevorzugt)
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::28bb:225b:f5fd:fffd%18(Bevorzugt)
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301989888
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-D1-6A-BB-1C-39-47-98-0E-7D
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert
```

VMnet1 is the Internal Network (To connect via SSH without a physical network)

VMnet8 is the VMware Bridge

Connecting to the local Network devices via IP (192.168.0.xx) over VPN works fine.

As i mentioned earlier, the other half of the world wide web is reachable.

Comment: Please run `nslookup -d2 inaccessible-site.com` (i.e. Use a hostname you cannot access) and [edit] your question with the output, then ping me.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator : I have updated my post with the output of nslookup. thanks

Comment: Your edit shows that the DNS server at 192.168.0.1 is not responding. Is this the DNS server you intend your computer to use? Is it the server that gets used when everything works correctly? Please [edit] your question to include what IP addresses your computer and your VMs are using, and your router. Post the output of `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 is my Router IP. If i use an other DNS Server (e.g. Google or OpenDNS) this Problem still appears. (Setting on Client and/or Server, still not able to connect). Is the installed Bridge Network Adapter from vmware/vbox causing this issue? Without the Virtual- Software evrything works fine.

Comment: Sry. Forget to "Ping" you @TwistyImpersonator

Comment: Does the IP addressing of your VM stations conflict with the IPs used on your physical network? It sounds like traffic intended for your router is going to your VMs instead.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator What do you mean with **conflict** ? My VMs received the IP over DHCP from my Router. (My Routers IP is '192.168.0.1' and the IP of my VM is '192.168.0.104').

Comment: None of your network adapters has an IP address in the same subnet as your router's IP of 192.168.0.1. This is why you cannot perform DNS lookups using the router. Which of these adapters is connected to the Internet?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's 
"Mobiler Breitbandadapter Mobilfunk". I use the LTE Modem of my Notebook. Why  is e.g. Google.com usable over vpn, but superuser.com isnt working?

Comment: I'm surprised *any* web access is possible. It looks like your adapter binding order has your VPN connection ahead of your mobile connection. When I get off mobile I'll find the steps to address this. In the meantime, can you disconnect the VPN connection? If so, does that help?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator yes, without the VPN connection   everything works fine. It doesnt matter if i use mobile or a "real" network. With VPN enabled, the DNS error appears on some sites. Strange. MANY THANKS TO YOU

Comment: so does disabling the VPN connection solve your problem? Or do you need things to work while the VPN is active?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator `>Or do you need things to work while the VPN is active?` Short answer: **Yep!** thanks again for your time.

Comment: Try [this](https://serverfault.com/a/402175/205065). I didn't want to post it as an answer unless it works (since I'm still a bit unclear what you're actually after).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No, i tried this before, without luck. If i Removed the checkmark from "Standardgateway for the Rmotenetwork"

Comment: Why do you have the DNS server 192.168.0.1 configured on your VPN at all?

Comment: .... i was able to visit superuser.com but cannot connect to my local devices :(   The IP 192.168.0.1 (my Router) is given by the qnap. I have changed this to 8.8.8.8 but without luck. I even changed the Metric Values from the Network Cards. And again without luck,

Comment: Which of your interfaces is connected to your local network? *That's* where your local DNS server should be configured.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator i give up on L2TP/IPSEC. Switched to OpenVPN. No DNS related issues. I'm able to browse the (complete) web AND use my local devices at home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN connection is configured with the DNS server 192.168.0.1. As demonstrated by your nslookup query attempt, this DNS server is the first to be queried by your computer.  Apparently your computer does not have a working route to this DNS server when your VPN connection is active.  This needs to be resolved.

Based on your comment:

> i give up on L2TP/IPSEC. Switched to OpenVPN. No DNS related issues. I'm able to browse the (complete) web AND use my local devices at home.

It appears something was not working with your VPN connection and that was preventing you from reaching this DNS server.

Comment: Thanks. But i didn't unterstand why the VPN without VM-software works without Problem. Again: even if i set it to 8.8.8.8. It doesnt works... I Tried this on a friends Windows pc. Nslookup Shows Me the local DNS Server (his Router ip). Everything works fine

Comment: Because with it enabled the 192.168.0.1 DNS server isn't accessible from your computer.  None of your network adapters are directly on the 192.168.0.1 subnet, so to reach that IP the traffic would have to be routed. This will go through your default gateway, which from your `ipconfig /all` output looks like that's going to be your Mobile network, which I'm guessing doesn't have a way to talk to that IP. You can figure out how your PC reaches the 192.168.0.1 IP address by running `tracert 192.168.0.1` *while everything is working* and you'll see what devices the packets are traversing through.